# Help with CMake parameters for catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a project that I'm trying to adapt to ROS.  Using `catkin_make`, it compiles ok, with clang++, but it fails on linking.
It needs to be linked with a series of object files (*.o) that are part of another (non-catkin) project.
I'm not sure how to add these dependencies to the target in CMakeLists.txt, and I don't know how to specify the equivalent CMake parameters in the catkin_make command.  There are a few other parameters I would like to pass as well.

In my `CMakeLists.txt`,  I've added all the `include_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()`.
I pass `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++` on the command line to catkin_make.  So far so good.

I would also like to pass the following compile parameters (or put them in my `CMakeLists.txt` file) but don't know how:
-fobjc-arc
-fPIC
-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++
-Weverything -Wno-undef -Wno-long-long -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-disabled-macro-expansion -Wno-weak-vtables -Wno-padded -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-pedantic -Werror

and the following link parameters, but also don't know how:
-rdynamic
-stdlib=libstdc++
(a series of object files to link together)  *Do I **need** to move the source files into my catkin_ws?*
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
-R/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

The reason for all these parameters is that they are part of the clang++ command line when building the project using make (outside of catkin).

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers,
Nap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156106/help-with-cmake-parameters-for-catkin_make/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100351/changing-cmake-cxx-flags-in-project

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-05-04**:
Thanks Thomas, but after I found the info mentioned my answer above, I was able to figure out everything I needed.  My project now is successfully built and I can debug it in Code::Blocks, which I'm using.